# Xamarin.iOS versioning during build

Tags: xamarin.ios, msbuild

I've been trying to get an automatic versioning system going for builds (mainly due to external crash analytics picking up each build as the same until I change the version manually). The format is simple, I take the `CFBundleShortVersionString` from the Info.plist, and append the current date and time (in `yyyyMMddmmss` format) as subversion.

The task I've put together for this:

```xml
<Project>
    <Target Name="BeforeBuild">
        <XmlPeek XmlInputPath="$(ProjectDir)Info.plist" Query="//dict/key[. = 'CFBundleShortVersionString']/following-sibling::string[1]">
            <Output TaskParameter="Result" ItemName="VersionNumber" />
        </XmlPeek>
        <PropertyGroup>
            <BuildNumber>$([System.DateTime]::Now.ToString(yyyyMMddmmss))</BuildNumber>
        </PropertyGroup>
        <XmlPoke XmlInputPath="$(ProjectDir)Info.plist" Query="//dict/key[. = 'CFBundleVersion']/following-sibling::string[1]" Value="$(VersionNumber).$(BuildNumber)" />
    </Target>
</Project>
```

However it fails with the following error:

```
Target BeforeBuild:
[...]/[...].csproj(1069,5): error MSB3733: Input file "[...]/Info.plist" cannot be opened. For security reasons DTD is prohibited in this XML document. To enable DTD processing set the DtdProcessing property on XmlReaderSettings to Parse and pass the settings into XmlReader.Create method.
Done building target "BeforeBuild" in project "[...].csproj" -- FAILED.
```

What am I doing wrong? There's not much info about this error, at least not much that I could find and would help fixing it.

Comment: Have you checked [this](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/5340/solved-auto-incrementing-build-number-version-number)?

Comment: Yes I did, and part of my code is from there. My issue is not technically with the logic of versioning, but XmlPeek being unusable as an MSBuild task.